# Error creating an instance of a proxy class

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-forms-designer

This is the error:

```
The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception.
```

This error ocurs when I try to instance my proxy class

```
namespace TesteWebService
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnPdv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SuporteTecnicoClientProxy proxy = new SuporteTecnicoClientProxy();=> **Here error**

                try
                {
                    TPDV pdv = proxy.getCnpjParceiro(txtCnpj.Text);
                    lblRazao.Text = pdv.RazaoSocial;
                    lblEndereco.Text = pdv.Endereco;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
                finally
                { }
        }
    }
}
```

My proxy class

```
namespace TesteWebService
{
    class SuporteTecnicoClientProxy : ClientBase<ISuporteTecnicoContract>, ISuporteTecnicoContract
    {
        public TPDV getCnpjParceiro(string _cnpj)
        {
            return this.Channel.getCnpjParceiro(_cnpj);
        }
    }
}
```

My Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ISuporteTecnicoContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{_cnpj}")]
        TPDV getCnpjParceiro(string _cnpj);
    }
```

My App.Config

```
<client>
    <endpoint adress="http://localhost:4600/SuporteTecnicoService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="V99SuporteTecnicoContracts.ISuporteTecnicoContract"
              behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior">
    </endpoint>
  </client>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WebBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

What is really going to generate the exception mentioned above. My Interface is other projet. A Class Library Project. So, I have 2 projects. A WCF project(Web Service) and my contract project(POCO class and Interface). This last project Class Library.

Comment: The error was in `System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility`; it's possible that the error was generated because you're trying to call a RESTful service like it's a SOAP service.  The client you specified in your config is using `webHttpBinding` - this is for REST.  But you're trying to consume it like it's a SOAP service.  For REST services, you need to use `HttpClient` or something similar.  REST does not use proxies.

Comment: I'm reading the book - Visual Studio 2010 - Step by step(John Sharp - Microsoft press). I read this book in this example. In this book he asks to use proxy

Comment: I don't have access to the book, but I'd double check the chapter you're in to make sure that you didn't overlook something.  I can't think of any way you could use a SOAP client to call a RESTful service, but that doesn't mean there isn't.

Comment: Ok, tim, I will review these issues. I am new to WCF web service